# How to archive Yahoo Group?

Tags: export, yahoo-groups

I'm in the same boat as every other YahooGroups owner, however probably most groups have been around 1999, when they were Yahoo Clubs.  We have STACKS of photos. We also have links, files and polls, and I've been manually checking those and copying what is still viable (either are active or can be resurrected on Archive.com.)

I work in a vaguely IT role which involves a lot of providing user support, but have very little scripting experience (mostly dabbling to make background bits of bigger projects work) and I usually had access to an expert with that aspect.

I'm looking through the various messages here and feel very much out of my depth. Is there anywhere someone could give me a simplified set of directions? (Not exactly talk to me like I'm a four year old, but at least give me a start as to how to apply the script and where I point it and start it running?)

Also, does anybody have any idea:
1) how much space I should allocate for approximately 34,000 messages?
2) how long it will take to download on a very rural connection?

It's a private group, and I gather the best way to start out would be to change the settings so I don't have to frack with the cookies issue.

And optionally: Is there a way to import the messages to Facebook?

Comment: There is a [Yahoo Groups project on archiveteam.org](https://www.archiveteam.org/index.php?title=Yahoo!_Groups), that seems to be active...  Oh well, [there are many more](https://www.google.com/search?q=archive+yahoo+group), but not 'one click solutions'. Don't you have a tech savvy friend or family member?

Comment: I'm usually the one solving other people's tech problems, but this is outside my areas. My usual scripting expert isn't available, and I don't know whether this falls into his skillset either. I have dabbled with guidance, but have no confidence in doing this.

Comment: The post is not a good fit for this site. I doesn't include enough details, needs more focus, etc. Probably this post is making reference to [Downloading entire archive of past messages of a Yahoo Group](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/135561/88163)

Answer (score 0):

I have no personal experience with this, but I have 2 suggestions that are more or less 'point and click':

1. For Windows: Use [PGOffline](http://www.personalgroupware.com/pgoffline-index.htm).
   14-day free trial, after which download and export is disabled (but view still works). Includes attachments. Stores data in a SQLite database internally.
   ["How To" YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4PIumS33e0)
2. Use the Chrome browser with the [Yahoo Messages Export plugin](http://yahoogroupedia.pbworks.com/w/page/93006447/Chrome%20Application%20To%20Download%20Messages)
   This downloads *only the messages*, and saves these in mbox format.